# Proving existence of following integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f(x)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dx$

I am required to prove that the integral exists (i.e. NOT CALCULATE IT!)

What am I supposed to use? Normally to prove the existence of an improper integral I would use the integral comparison theorem (not sure on the name in english) which states:

$\int^{\infty}_{1}f(x)dx$ converges iff $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} f(n)$ converges. However this only pertains to the lower bound being 1?!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: The definite integral is NOT a function of x.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^4}$ is obviously finite, and $\int_{|x|>1}\frac{dx}{1+x^4}$... is obviously finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\int_1^\infty$ exists and (by symmetry) $\int_{-\infty}^{-1}$ exists, and $\int_{-1}^1$ poses no problem at all, then the whole integral exists.